# Which distributed version control system has the best GUI front-ends for Windows?

Tags: windows, version-control, dvcs

At my workplace we are using CVS as the version control system. Since we are using Windows mostly, TortoiseCVS and WinCVS serve as the GUI front-ends to CVS.

Is there anything like those front-ends for one of the distributed VCS (bzr, hg, git)? I know we could use the command line but that is not an option.

I've already tried Bazaar and was disappointed by TortoiseBzr.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Mercurial](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/). It has a [tortoise shell plugin](http://tortoisehg.sourceforge.net/) and [integrates with Eclipse](http://www.vectrace.com/mercurialeclipse/).

Comment: The shell plugin doesn't support 64-bit last time I checked. TortoiseBZR for Bazaar claims to.

Answer (score 1):

Mercurial

TortoiseHG for shell and [MercurialEclipse](http://trac-hg.assembla.com/mercurialeclipse)

Answer (score 1):

Mercurial seems to have the best GUI tools for Windows at the moment, but CVS or SVN GUI tools seem to be better, I hope this would change in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Mercurial has the best support when it comes to DVCS. There's TortoiseHg for integration with Explorer and Nautilus (Linux) and there are two Eclipse plug-ins (MercurialEclipse and Merclipse) that work. The former offers nearly everything Mercurial offers, including Rebase, Push, Pull, graphical history, workspace synchronization etc.

Answer (score 0):

I like bzr, but have not used the tortoise plugin; I believe Canonical are working on some front-ends for it as well.  Oh, and of course there's an Eclipse plugin, so you can use your IDE as the GUI for it.